# Replacing for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add id in a components array. id's will be incrementing based on the no. of components.

```
  component_names = ['test1', 'test2'];
```

I want to create a new array components which will become :

```
components = [{id:1, name: 'test1'}, {id:2, name: 'test2'}]
```

// The ids will increment as the no. of components increase.

What I am trying:

```
let arr=[];
for(let i=0;i<component_names.length;i++){
    arr.push({id:i+1, name: component_names[i]});
}
```

The above solution works but can I do the same with any of the higher order functions in javascript?

Comment: Yes. You are taking an array of items and manipulating them all in similar fashion to output an array of the same length. This is the primary use-case for [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: It's look like you want to create a JSON object.

Comment: @probitaille There is no such thing as a "JSON Object". OP wants to create an array of objects.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question, since it specifically talks of using a higher-order function. Normal people don't set out to do higher-order functions for fun!

Nevertheless here is my tip.

If component_names is an array, try 

    component_names.map((item, index)=>{"item:",item,"index:",index})

This will print out something useful. You can adjust it to deliver your homework.

Answer (score 3):

A simple [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will work, where parameter 1 is the item and parameter 2 is the index.

```js
let component_names = ['test1', 'test2']

let result = component_names.map((itm, idx) => ({id:++idx,name:itm}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = component_names.map((name, index) => ({ name: name, id: index + 1 }));
```